# How do I expand image to full view when being tapped in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my project I'm using a `UICollectionView` for displaying images and I'm also using `UIImageView` in `UICollectionViewCell`.
All I want is when I tap on a image it should expand and show on fullscreen.
For this I've created a new view takes a `UIImageView` on it and apply TapGesture on `UICollectionViewCells`.
The expanded image open in the next view but isn't presented in the frame I give it.
and also when i click on any pic it removed from the collection view. please tell me how to reload `UICollectionViewCells`[image]
Please suggest me how to put image on the prescribed frames.
I'm sharing my code

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    imgview = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    imgview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,160, 160)];

    imgview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgview];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(expandImage:)];
    tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [imgview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    imgview.tag = indexPath.row;
    [imgview addGestureRecognizer:tapped];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgview];

    return cell;
}

-(void)expandImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recogniser
{
    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.size.width , self.view.frame.size.height)];
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view1];

    UIButton *closeButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(310, 10, 50, 40)];
    [closeButton setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Closetab) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [view1 addSubview:closeButton];

    UIImageView *photoView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-200)];
    [photoView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [view1 addSubview:photoView];
    photoView.accessibilityIdentifier = @"nature2.png";

    UIImageView *photoView1 = (UIImageView*)recogniser.view;
    photoView1.accessibilityIdentifier = @"nature2.png";

    //photoView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    // photoView.accessibilityIdentifier = @"apple1.png";

    photoView1.contentMode =  UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

    //photoView1.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [view1 addSubview:photoView1];  
}
```

Comment: i don't have enough reputation(15) score to add snapshot put my ques vote up then i will add snapshot of it

Comment: Does the imageView appear? Is the frame wrong?

Comment: now add some snap shot.now you have a reputation.

Comment: imageview frames are not set correctly now i set it and works fine. but the problem arise is when i click on any pic it removed from the collection view. please tell me how to reload uicollectionview cells

Comment: @yankitPatel i add my screenshot now check it

Comment: do you want to see photo in a full screen ???

Comment: yes i want pic to cover full view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is better to add view in a window.so it is display in full screen.Use Following Code.

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.size.width , self.view.frame.size.height)];
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view.window addSubview:view1];
```

Comment: please if you can add swift version

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to achieve this would be to push to a new view that you display the full screen picture, instead of adding it as a subview.

You can also customize the transition animation of the navigation controller to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Ok don't take anything for granted, because one thing im sure of, is that looking at that code made me confused. But here is how i see it, and what went wrong:

```
    UIImageView *photoView1 = (UIImageView*)recogniser.view;
    [view1 addSubview:photoView1];
```

With those 2 lines you are taking out your view from cell and putting it in this new view1.
So just allocating new UIImageVIew and setting its image could solve it.
And some more suggestions:

```
    imgview = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    imgview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,160, 160)];
```

Here that first line of code isn't doing anything. You set object, and then you set that object again.
Next thing is do not add subviews in **cellForItemAtIndexPath** without removing previously added. When dequeuing cells, you are using the same cells over and over again, so you will creat memory leak by stacking views on top of each other. You could even omit all that adding stuff by creating custom cell with its own UIImageView. Next there is no need to use gesture recognition, CollectionView have this one delegate:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You can replace your **expandImage** method with it, inside you would just simply get your image from **imagearray**.
And lastly there's this beautiful library ready to use for you, [MHFacebookImageViewer](https://github.com/michaelhenry/MHFacebookImageViewer).

Answer (score 1):

Add `imageview` on `navigationController.view`

```
UIImageView *imgView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:imgView];
```

Answer (score 0):

i done the above by this code
firstly added tap gesture 
then apply the following code

```
-(void)expandImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recogniser
{

    view1.hidden = NO;

    UIImageView *photoView1 = (UIImageView*)recogniser.view;
    photoView1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 510);
    photoView1.accessibilityIdentifier = @"nature2.png";

    //photoView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    // photoView.accessibilityIdentifier = @"apple1.png";

    photoView1.contentMode =  UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

    photoView1.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [view1 addSubview:photoView1];
    }
```